# Java chat socket doesn't show messages after adding file sender

Tags: java, sockets, chat

I wrote a chat client that worked fine until I decided to add some file sender thing which should send a file from the client to the server. After I added the lines for the file sender it doesn't show messages anymore.

I think the trouble is here, having two try statements in run().

```
   public void run(){

    InputStream input = null;

    try{
        input = socket.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader inReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        BufferedWriter outReader = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));

        //Citeste calea fisierului
        String filename = inReader.readLine();
        if(filename.equals("")){
            //Trimit status READY la client
            outReader.write("READY\n");
            outReader.flush();
        }

        FileOutputStream wr = new FileOutputStream(new File("C://tmp/"+filename));
        byte[] buffer = new byte[socket.getReceiveBufferSize()];
        int bytesReceived = 0;
        while((bytesReceived = input.read(buffer)) > 0){
            wr.write(buffer,0,bytesReceived);
        }

    }

    catch(IOException e){
        Logger.getLogger(ConectareClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null,e);
    }

    try{
        //Inregistreaza firul curent in listaObiecte
        listaObiecte.addElement(this);

        System.out.println("\n Fir de executie nou");
        System.out.println(this.toString());
        System.out.println(listaObiecte.toString());

        //Bucla
        while(true){
            //Se citeste mesajul din fluxul de intrare trimis de client
            String mesaj = fluxIntrare.readUTF();
            //Se transmite mesajul catre toti clientii conectati
            transmite(mesaj);
        }
    }
  //Tratare exceptie conexiune 
  catch (IOException e){
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
  finally{
        //Stergere fir curent din listaObiecte
        listaObiecte.removeElement(this);

        System.out.println("\n Fir de executie inchis");
        System.out.println(this.toString());
        System.out.println(listaObiecte.toString());

        try{
            //Inchidere socket
            socket.close();
            input.close();
        }
        //Tratare exceptie conexiune 
        catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }    
  }  
}

    private static void transmite(String mesaj){
    //Enumerare generata de lista firelor de executie
    Enumeration enm = listaObiecte.elements();

    //Cat timp mai sunt elemente in enumerare
    while(enm.hasMoreElements()){
        //Se initializeaza cu null referinta firului curent
        ConectareClient firDestinatie = null;

        //Se protejeaza vectorul firelor de acces simultan
        synchronized(listaObiecte){
            //Se memoreaza referinta catre firul curent
            firDestinatie = (ConectareClient) enm.nextElement();
        }
    //Referinta valida
        if(firDestinatie != null){
            try{
                //Se protejeaza fluxul de iesire de acces simultan
                synchronized(firDestinatie.fluxIesire){
                    //Scriere mesaj in flux de iesire
                    firDestinatie.fluxIesire.writeUTF(mesaj);
                }
                //Mesajul este transmis
                firDestinatie.fluxIesire.flush();
            }
            catch(IOException e){
                firDestinatie.stop();
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: May the client send a file called `..\windows\system32\user32.dll`?

Comment: well, the file sending part was taken from another application i wrote and it was running just fine, sending all kind of files.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly the problem I tried to tell you. When the client sends a filename that contains `..`, the server will overwrite completely unrelated files, which it shouldn't. You have to check for *bad filenames* before creating the file.

Answer (score 1):

I've downloaded and tried your code. In short, your problem is thread deadlock. You have two threads, one on the server side, and one on the client side, each waiting for the otherone to do something so that the first thread can continue as well.

In more details, here's what's up:

- the ClientChat class sends the filename to the server at line 260, and then waits for the server to send something back (a string with "READY"), before it continues with the actual file send
- on the other side, the ConectareClient class stops at line 38 waits for something to be send from the client before continuing (and sending the "READY" status message, which in turn the client is waiting for).

My advice to you is this:

This looks a lot like a homework asignement that some dusty old professor gave to you:) And it looks like the guy gave this to you without first going through the basics of software development. I'm not gonna editorialise here, but here's a few practical pointers that might help you:

- use an IDE such as Eclipse. Don't write code in the command line using notepad. In this case Eclipse would benefit you immensly just for the ease with which you could debug your code to sppot such trivial errors. Here's what you should do: Download Eclipse, create a Java standard project, copy all your .java files and paste them in the "src" folder of the Eclipse project. Then add some break points at the lines I mention above , start both the client and the server, try to send a file and see what happends in your code.
- Make unit tests! This is very important, no matter what your professor and your colegues might say. Doing unit tests will have a twofold benefit on your coding: 1. it will help you spot such refactoring regression errors easily. 2. it will force you to write good clean code, with individual methods for each task etc.
- While having the server/client low level threads and sockets knowledge is not bad, a better way to achieve what you're trying to do in this project is to use Java Messenger Service. It's a framework that does exactly what you want, namely send and receive all kind of stuff (primitives, objects etc) in a synchronous or asynchronous fashion and all the scaffolding is already done for you, you only have to implement the business logic. Look it up, it might help you a lot.

Comment: thanks for the advices, i will try deleting the wait for READY part and see what's happening

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a small logic error in ConnectareClient.java. The condition to send "READY", I believe should be a NOT condition, otherwise it would never send that reply to the client and proceed with the file writing. I tried it out already and I could see the file is getting copied from the client to the server.

Below is the code change that I did in ConnectareClient.java

```
//Citeste calea fisierului
String filename = inReader.readLine();

// this seems should be a NOT condition
if(!filename.equals("")){
    //Trimit status READY la client
    outReader.write("READY\n");
    outReader.flush();
}
```

Comment: What is the error? The only other thing that I change is making the c:/temp point to my temp directory in Mac. You need to be more specific if you want us to help you instead of saying that it is not working

Comment: Check if your client is getting the READY message from the server after the modification.